# Outlook calendar background sync from add ins

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

I'm researching sync new events to outlook calendar from outlook add-ins , I am try to sync new events from outlook add ins to outlook calendar, i am able to sync events using REST API (me/events) in outlook add ins to click the sync button

but i want sync new events data without open my add-ins ,sync events every time open outlook calendar , any possible to trigger sync event when i open an outlook calendar , it is possible or not ,any handler is available ?

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such an event for web-based add-ins. See [Activation rules for contextual Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/activation-rules) for more information. You may consider developing VSTO based add-in to synchronize calendars automatically.

Also you may consider placing a ribbon button which can start the sync process. Read more about that in the [Add-in commands for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook) article.